# Python: Function: not recognizing dependencies

Tags: python, function, module

I am quite new to writing modules in Python.
I use Python 3.5

I have a script called describeToolbox.py that contain functions that I would like to be able to call, like this one:

```
#describeToolbox.py
import shelve

def getRawData(prefix):
    shelfFile = shelve.open('data'+prefix)
    df = shelfFile['data'+prefix]
    shelfFile.close()
    return df
```

This is meant to retrieve a dataFrame from a shelve file
In my console now, I write the following statements:

```
In [7]:import shelve
       import describeToolbox as TB

In [8]:TB.getRawData('Myprefix')

Out [8]:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-9-67160af666cc> in <module>()
    ----> 1 TB.getRawData('Myprefix')

    C:\Users\Math\Documents\Docs\Commos\Notebooks\describeToolbox.py in getRawData(prefix)
          1 def getRawData(prefix):
    ----> 2     shelfFile = shelve.open('data'+prefix)
          3     df = shelfFile['data'+prefix]
          4     shelfFile.close()
          5     return df

    NameError: name 'shelve' is not defined
```

It gives me an error message saying that the module 'shelve', the dependency, is not defined.

Basically I dont know where is the correct place to import all the dependencies so that my function can load them when I want to import it.

I would like to write a depository of functions I use often in one module and call them when needed.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `shelve` needs to be imported in each module that uses it.

Comment: but it is imported in my case, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. Something else is going on. There is no reason that shouldn't work.

Comment: I updated my question, to show you that it happens even though I import it in my script and in the console. This is really confusing me.